# MYSQL how to covert table from relationship from onetoone to onetomany merging its columns in to rows

Tags: mysql

In Mysql DB i have TABLE that looks like this

```
ID Mobile1 Mobile2 Mobile3

1 1111111  1222222 1333333
2 2111111  2222222 2333333
3 3111111  3222222 3333333
```

what is the proper MYSQL Query to be

```
ID Mobile
1  1111111
1  1222222
1  1333333
2  2111111
2  2222222
2  2333333
3  3111111
3  3222222
3  3333333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UNION ALL query to convert the columns into rows:

```
select id, mobile1 as mobile
from yt
union all
select id, mobile2 as mobile
from yt
union all
select id, mobile3 as mobile
from yt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/629ab/1)